Is there any way to dynamically highlight specific letter(s) in a word, without making every single letter a separate <span> element?
I have a div with a handful of spans, each span containing one word. The user can tap/click a word to select it, but I'm also trying to implement keyboard input.
I'd like to highlight each letter in any matching words as the user types.
For example, let's say we have these five words:
banana
cat
baby
ball
candy
If the user types "ba" I'd like to highlight the first two letters in "banana" , "baby" , and "ball" (then if they type an 'n', it would un-highlight the letters in "baby" and "ball" and would highlight the first three letters of "banana" only)
These words are all dynamically generated from a word list array, so I'm hoping there might be a way to achieve this highlighting without having to wrap every single letter in a span.
Is this possible?

a highlighted ban on top of a normal banana

This question is similar to: JavaScript find string and highlight. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You don't have to wrap every single letter up-front, but yes you'll have to wrap every sequence of letters that you want to highlight

Maybe the following is what you want? It will also highlight letters or letter groups in the middle of words:


// define variables for the elements in HTML
const words = document.querySelectorAll('#text>span');
const input = document.getElementById('matchText');

input.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 const rx=new RegExp(input.value,"ig");

 words.forEach(w=>w.innerHTML=w.textContent.replace(rx,`<span class="highlight">$&</span>`));
 
});


 
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<p id="text">
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>ball</span>
  <span>ballistic</span>
  <span>cat</span>
  <span>chat</span>
  <span>change</span>
  <span>chap</span>
  <span>character</span>
  <span>color</span>
  <span>people</span>
  <span>peel</span>
  <span>peon</span>
</p>
<input type="text" id="matchText" name="matchingText">



Update
After diligently reading the question I prepared the above snippet so it would find the user-entered fragments anywhere in each word. OP's comment made it clear now that that was a misunderstanding, so here is a modified solution that will highlight the letters only at the beginning of each word:


// define variables for the elements in HTML
const words = document.querySelectorAll('#text>span');
const input = document.getElementById('matchText');

input.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 const rx=new RegExp("^"+input.value,"ig");

 words.forEach(w=>w.innerHTML=w.textContent.replace(rx,`<span class="highlight">$&</span>`));
 
});


 
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<p id="text">
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>ball</span>
  <span>ballistic</span>
  <span>cat</span>
  <span>chat</span>
  <span>change</span>
  <span>chap</span>
  <span>character</span>
  <span>color</span>
  <span>people</span>
  <span>peel</span>
  <span>peon</span>
</p>
<input type="text" id="matchText" name="matchingText">



The change concerns the definition of the regular expression rx:
const rx=new RegExp("^"+input.value,"ig");

It now always starts with a ^, thereby demanding the pattern to be at the beginning of each <span>.

If you decide to use a solution like this, it would be advisable to include an aria-label on the span elements, like "Banana". This way, visually impaired people can still understand the content, and it doesn't affect those without disabilities at all.

Ah — spoke too soon. I missed the bit about it highlighting in the middle of words too. Is there a way to modify the RegExp() call so it only matches words that start with the string?

I changed my answer accordingly. Please check.

Aha! Thanks, I knew it was some tiny edit like that! I even tried changing the '"ig" to "^ig" after looking up some stuff about regexes, but I didn't fully grasp it and obvs that didn't work. Didn't occur to me I was putting it in the wrong param haha... Thanks again!

To prevent the addon of span element:
You may use the linear-gradient css style to highlight specific letter sequence. Please modify the code below to cope with your need since you may need to highlight multiple letters occurrences within a span element.
/* index.css */
/* this may be applied if you use <p> other than <span> to wrap your text
p {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* update: to ensure each letter has same width */
span {
    font-family: monospace;
}


 <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Type to highlight">
  <div id="wordContainer">
    <span>banana</span>
    <span>cat</span>
    <span>baby</span>
    <span>ball</span>
    <span>candy</span>
  </div>

<script>
function highlightWords() {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();
  const spans = document.querySelectorAll("#word-container span");

  spans.forEach((span) => {
    const word = span.textContent.toLowerCase();
    const wordLength = word.length;
    const inputLength = searchInput.length;

    // Find the start and end index of the search input within the word
    const startIndex = word.indexOf(searchInput);
    const endIndex = startIndex + inputLength;

    if (startIndex !== -1 && searchInput.length > 0) {
      const startPercentage = (startIndex / wordLength) * 100;
      const endPercentage = (endIndex / wordLength) * 100;

      // Apply the gradient background
      span.style.background = `linear-gradient(
        to right,
        white 0%,
        white ${startPercentage}%,
        yellow ${startPercentage}%,
        yellow ${endPercentage}%,
        white ${endPercentage}%,
        white 100%
      )`;
    } else {
      span.style.background = "none"; // Reset background if no match
    }
  });
}
</script>


This solution assumes that all letters have the same width.

Oh, @HeikoTheißen thank you for pointing this out. Maybe we can add "font-family: monospace" to the span element.

You can get the text and input and then split the text into words using split(), then iterate over that array and check if the value startsWith() whatever string the input is passing during an input eventListener. Placing the logic in a map method you can reformat the searched string and concatenate the leftover part of the word using substring() or splice(). Join the mapped array and then set the elements innerHTML to the newly formatted string with a highlight class.
See further comments in the code snippet


// define variables for the elements in HTML
const par = document.querySelector('#text');
const input = document.querySelector('#matchText');

// callback passing in the event
const searchtext = e => {
  // define the input value toLowerCase
  const searchText = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // get the text content of the element you wish to search through
  const textCont = par.textContent;

  // split the text into words using a whitespace
  const words = textCont.split(' ');

  // iterate over the words with map and define word
  const highlightedText = words.map(word => {

    // check and see if the word startWith the searchText string
    if (word.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchText) && searchText !== '') {

      // return the formatted string of the word 
      // with the letters highlighted using substring
      return `<span class="highlight">${word.substring(0, searchText.length)}</span><span>${word.substring(searchText.length, word.length)}</span>`;
    }

    // return the non-matching words in teh original string
    return word;

    // create a string with the array values using .join()
  }).join(' ');

  // set the innerHTML to the new string containing the highlighted string
  par.innerHTML = highlightedText;
}

// eventListener using an input event, pass the callback
input.addEventListener('input', searchtext);
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<p id="text">
  <span>Banana</span>
  <span>ball</span>
  <span>ballistic</span>
  <span>cat</span>
  <span>chat</span>
  <span>change</span>
  <span>chap</span>
  <span>character</span>
  <span>color</span>
  <span>people</span>
  <span>peel</span>
  <span>peon</span>
</p>
<input type="text" id="matchText" name="matchingText">



